# How to fetch data from the firebase with unique document id and store it into the variable as mentioned in the below code to use in a _profilename?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ProfileScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfileScreen({Key key, this.animationController}) : super(key: key);
  final AnimationController animationController;
  @override
  _ProfileScreenState createState() => _ProfileScreenState();
}

class _ProfileScreenState extends State<ProfileScreen>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  User user;

  Animation<double> topBarAnimation;

  List<Widget> listViews = <Widget>[];
  final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
  double topBarOpacity = 0.0;
  @override
  void initState() {
    topBarAnimation = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(
        CurvedAnimation(
            parent: widget.animationController,
            curve: Interval(0, 0.5, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn)));

    scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (scrollController.offset >= 24) {
        if (topBarOpacity != 1.0) {
          setState(() {
            topBarOpacity = 1.0;
          });
        }
      } else if (scrollController.offset <= 24 &&
          scrollController.offset >= 0) {
        if (topBarOpacity != scrollController.offset / 24) {
          setState(() {
            topBarOpacity = scrollController.offset / 24;
          });
        }
      } else if (scrollController.offset <= 0) {
        if (topBarOpacity != 0.0) {
          setState(() {
            topBarOpacity = 0.0;
          });
        }
      }
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          //for circle avtar image
          _getHeader(),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          _profileName("Pranshul"),
          SizedBox(
            height: 14,
          ),
          _heading("Personal Details"),
          SizedBox(
            height: 6,
          ),
          _detailsCard(),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ),
          _heading("Other Details"),
          SizedBox(
            height: 6,
          ),
          _settingsCard(),
        ],
      )),
    );
  }

  Widget _getHeader() {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                //borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                image: DecorationImage(
                    fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    image: NetworkImage(
                        "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/c5/97/1e/c5971e1f8181a1d85a35f47456af4db2.gif"))
                // color: Colors.orange[100],
                ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _profileName(String name) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.80, //80% of width,
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          name,
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black, fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _heading(String heading) {
    return Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.80, //80% of width,
      child: Text(
        heading,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _detailsCard() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Card(
        elevation: 4,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            //row for each deatails
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.email),
              title: Text("Pranshulagrawal9269@gmail.com"),
            ),
            Divider(
              height: 0.6,
              color: Colors.black87,
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.phone),
              title: Text("72320xxxxx"),
            ),
            Divider(
              height: 0.6,
              color: Colors.black87,
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.location_on),
              title: Text("Rajasthan"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _settingsCard() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Card(
        elevation: 4,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.topic),
              title: Text("Pranshul Agrawal"),
            ),
            Divider(
              height: 0.6,
              color: Colors.black87,
            ),
            //row for each deatails
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.settings),
              title: Text("3417-7885-xxxx"),
            ),
            Divider(
              height: 0.6,
              color: Colors.black87,
            ),
            ListTile(
              leading: Icon(Icons.dashboard_customize),
              title: Text("RJAOKFTGBVFG75468"),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

How to fetch data from firestore with the uid as the authentication uid provided by the firebase while login or signup and use as an argument in the function as _profilename(String name).

Want to fetch the data and show in the profile section having different different function of each data must passed a variable to them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to see any Firestore related code in your question but as @Frank has mentioned in the comment that this use-case is pretty common.
To put it in simple steps, it'll look like:

1. Get UID of current user
2. Make request to Firestore with document ID as UID
   (It is not clear if the document ID is the user UID itself but I'll proceed with the example)

Please make sure you have the latest version of the Firebase SDK installed:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core: "^0.7.0"
  firebase_auth: "^0.20.1"
  cloud_firestore: "^0.16.0+1"

//Latest version while answering this ^
```

Fetching current user  UID and then the document:

```
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

if (auth.currentUser != null) {
  print(auth.currentUser.uid);
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('users')
    .doc(auth.currentUser.uid)
    .get()
    .then((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
      if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
        print('Document data: ${documentSnapshot.data()}');
        //Set the relevant data to variables as needed
      } else {
        print('Document does not exist on the database');
      }
    });
}
```

If the UID is stored in the document as a field and if different than the document ID, then you can use [queries](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#querying).
Please let me know if you have any more questions!

Comment: fetchdata() {
    var firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    CollectionReference collectionReference =
        Firestore.instance.collection('users');
    collectionReference.snapshots().listen((snapshot) {
      setState(() {
        data = snapshot.documents[0].data();
        name = data['Aadharno'].toString();
        print(name);
      });
    });

Comment: tried this but can't assign uid in the document as it takes only int value

Comment: @PranshulAgrawal please share screenshot of the error

Comment: `.doc()` clearly accepts a string value too as mentioned [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#documentsnapshot)

Comment: The method 'doc' isn't defined for the type 'QuerySnapshot'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'doc'.

Comment: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'. this error is generated while using current user uid in document[]

Comment: @PranshulAgrawal can I please get a screenshot of it? Also it's just `.doc()` and not `.document()` just incase you've made a typing error.

Comment: as i fetching the data it will take time till an error will be displayed on my screen before loading the data how i will resolve it

Comment: @PranshulAgrawal kindly post a separate question for another issue. Also you can mark this answer as accepted if it resolved your original question

Comment: @PranshulAgrawal do you have any issue with this specific issue?